# Global approach to redirect on login page in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know how I can design my application using global approach for such scenario

1. Redirect on login page if user does not authenticated or session has expired
2. Redirect on login page if user does have other role and try to access page which does not fall under that role.
3. Redirect on login page if requested for page that does not present in application.

Comment: You can do all of these with Attributes and Filters. A quick google will yield lots of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can create a ActionFilter see this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Or Another shortcut way to do this in MVC3 you can check Session or authentication in Master page top of the page razor code ie: `_LayOut.cshtm`l like this:

```
@model CustomerModel{
if(Session["CustomerId"]==null)
    RedirectToActionResult("Index","Home");

}
```

Note: For this you need to inherit all of your views with _LayOut.cshtml and don't inherit /Home/Index view with master page because It will run recursively and you got timeout error.